# Need to call one sub class of an interface using object of another sub class

Tags: java, class, interface

I have an `interface`

```
public interface I
{
    // an abstract method m1();
}
```

I have `class` `A` and `class B`

```
class A implements I
{
    public void m1()
    {
         System.out.println("m1 Method From A");
    }
}

class B implements I
{
    public void m1()
    {
        System.out.println("m1 Method From B");
    }
}
```

Can i call the `m1` method of `class B` using `object` created to `class A` ?

For Example I have created `object` of `A` like `I i = new A();`

If I write as `i.m1()` `m1` method of `class B` should be invoked

Note : There is no `super class or sub class` relation between `class A` and `class B`

It's just a doubt whether i can call or not

Thank You ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a dependency/association of type `B` to `A`. This can easily be done by introducing a class member of type `B` within `A`

Something like this:

```
class A implements I
{
    private B b = new B();

    public void m1()
    {
         System.out.println("m1 Method From A");
         b.m2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my doubt is whether i can call `m1()` of `class B` without creating `object` to `class B`

Comment: This solution is using association. Without association you can not call the m1() of class B from A.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflections:

**Interface**

```
public interface I {
    public void m1();
}
```

**Class A**

```
public class A implements I
{
    public void m1()
    {
        System.out.println("m1 method from A");
        
        try {
            Method sampleMethod = B.class.getMethod("m1" , new Class[] {});
            sampleMethod.invoke(B.class.newInstance()); 
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

**Class B**

```
public class B implements I {
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("m1 method from B");
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     A a = new A();
     a.m1();    
}
```

op:

> m1 Method From A
>
> m1 Method from B